# Creating large bootstrap table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Hi I am a little new to Ruby on Rails and this should be pretty simple.  I want to make a large bootstrap table, while also being able to loop through my model/database table.

```
       
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">I</th>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Time</th>
            <th scope="col">Duration</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Company</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
<% 96.times |i| %>
      <% @workorders.each do |workorder| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= i %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.id %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.time %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.duration %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.price %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.name %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.company %></td>
      <td><%= workorder.city %></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

           
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
```

I have verified that when I do just a `.each` loop over `@workorders` it works fine.  However, when I run my Rails application with the above code I get a syntax error, nothing too detailed.  What would be the proper syntax to create this 96-length bootstrap table, while also looping through my model/sqlite table?

Comment: If should be `96.times do |i|` and I guess this is your "nothing too detailed" error message. Let me know if this solved the issue

Comment: ruby syntact is either `10.times {|i| }` or `10.times do |i| end` but there isn't `10.times |i|` because it's missing block-opening statement.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant! Thank you so much! Adding a `do` after `96.times` solved everything.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).